# how can I get specific value of an array list using stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have an ArrayList of **Person** ordered by ids the 0 as the id:1 the 1 as the id:2 etc and I want to get only some of them in another ArrayList using stream
here's what I tried but it don't seems to work:

```java
public ArrayList<Person> getPersonfoById(int... ids) {
    if (IntStream.of(ids).anyMatch(id -> id > totalpersonnumber)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("the given person id" + Arrays.asList(IntStream.of(ids).filter(i -> i >= totalpersonnumber).boxed().toArray()) + " dosen't exist in " + fileName);
    }
    try (IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(ids)) {
        return (ArrayList<Pokemon>) stream.boxed().map(x -> myArrayOfPerson.get(x))
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) in combination with [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)?

Comment: "I want to get only some of them in another ArrayList" what's your filter criteria?

Comment: I have an array list of **Person** a person is defined by _an id, a name and his gender_ all my Person are in an array list I want with this method to enter ids like 1,2,18,20 and get a new array list of person with only the ids I gave

Answer (score 2):

Since the input of selected ids might vary, the best way is to use `List::contains` in the filter's predicate:

```
// Get a list of ids at the beginning once and use with each iteration
List<Integer> idsList = Arrays.stream(ids).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Person> personList myArrayOfPerson.stream()         // Stream<Person>
    .filter(person -> idsList.contains(person.getId()))  // Stream<Person> of the given ids
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                       // List<Person>
```

This is the solution where the `id` is a **part** of the object `Person` and not driven by the behavior of the `List` which is not a good practice.

However, if you insist to get these on the certain positions in the `List`, then a bit different approach is required:

```
List<Person> personList = Arrays.stream(ids)             // IntStream
    .boxed()                                             // Stream<Integer>
    .map(myArrayOfPerson::get)                           // Stream<Person>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                       // List<Person>
```

This is a **fail-fast** approach which doesn't handle the ids out of the bounds. You should know that `List::get` might throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so to avoid this, filter out the `ids` which doesn't fit the list size:

```
List<Person> personList = Arrays.stream(ids)             // IntStream
    .filter(id -> id > 0 && id < myArrayOfPerson.size()) // IntStream (wanted ids only)
    .boxed()                                             // Stream<Integer>
    .map(myArrayOfPerson::get)                           // Stream<Person>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                       // List<Person>
```

An alternative way would be to return null objects for unusual ids or log a message or handle it another way which is out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: I like the way @Nikolas writes the solution, he always adds up comment at each step in #stream, making it comfortable for newbies to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this

```
Arrays.stream(ids).filter(id->id>20).toArray();
```

For stream uses visit this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm)